# PSEXEC OpenSCManager fails when execute command for workgroup from domain

Tags: operating-systems, administrator, psexec, sysinternals

I am trying to run [sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)' PSEXEC from my domain machine to workgroup machine and vice versa:

Cmd Line:

```
Psexec \\\MachineName -u "username" -p "password" -i -s -d cmd.exe
```

- If I run this command from a workgroup machine to a domain machine, 
  sometimes it works fine and sometimes it fails
- workgroup to workgroup: fails
- domain to wokrgroup: fails

I get this message stating the reason for the failure: `Access denied with OpenSCManager`. I know that PSEXEC uses OpenSCManager, but I'm not able to figure out the reason behind the denied access.

My settings:

- administrator account on both the workgroup and domain machine
- command prompt in administrator mode
- Firewall is off
- Network sharing is ON

PSEXEC does not give an invalid username/password error; I've also checked that the credentials are correct using `net use`.

Please help me with some info regarding whether this kind of access is allowed/feasible or not.

Comment: One may like this or not, the solution is luckily pretty simple. UAC remote restrictions can be disabled by setting the registry value LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to 1:

Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
Value: LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
Data: 1 (to disable, 0 enables filtering)
Type: REG_DWORD (32-bit)

Comment: since you found how to solve your issue, it will be better if you post this comment as an answer, and accept it.

Comment: I've already posted the solution above